# É má prática retornar ViewModel a partir de um WebService?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-service

É uma prática ruim usar a mesma classe que é usada como *ViewModel*, que uma *Action* passa para a *View*, para retornar dados de um *WebService*? (tipo aqueles métodos marcados com `[WebMethod]`)

Eu imagino que não, mas pode ser que me dê problemas algum dia, então gostaria de saber se alguém pode ver algum problema, ou se já teve algum problema real em se fazer isso.

**Porque eu imaginei que não:** o view model, é um objeto de dados que serão enviados para o usuário, codificado na forma de HTML... então ele já representa algo que pode ser enviado para o mundo exterior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considero uma [ViewModel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_model) em sí, como uma representação de um modelo para uma view. Não vejo como um problema o retorno da `ViewModel` a partir de uma `Action` ou `Web Service`, desde que a informação que está sendo retornada é o que você pretende com este método.

O problema, em um caso assim, é se um dos casos necessita de muitas informações (exemplo: muitas propriedades, para uma visualização detalhada de uma entidade) e outra com poucas (exemplo: uma listagem em formato de `grid`), sendo que em casos assim, é preferível realizar a separação em diferentes `ViewModel`'s, principalmente quando se trabalha com informações distribuídas (Web Services, APIs) onde o tráfego é algo importante. Se a intenção do método é a mesma para ambos os casos, não vejo como problema, uma vez que você economiza código.

A ViewModel não é enviada para o usuário em formato HTML, isto acontece quando a sua camada de apresentação renderiza HTML para o usuário. O que é comum, é que no corpo de requisições a APIs ou Serviços Web, esta ViewModel venha serializada de acordo com o que foi solicitado no Header Request (content-type), e este formato pode variar de acordo com o suporte da API ou Serviço Web. Os mais comuns são: [`json`](http://www.json.org/), [`xml`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) e [`soap`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP).